# How to set bootstrap form-control padding to 0 px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, wicket, padding

I have a problem with setting the Bootstrap form control padding to 0. I tried adding the `.form-control` class in styles but without success. I believe it should be possible to override some properties of CSS classes in the style block.

How do I set the `.form-control` padding to 0?

```
<wicket:head xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/">
 <styles>
     .form-control {
        padding: 0px;
     }

 </styles>
</wicket:head>
<wicket:panel xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="submit" value="Request" class="btn btn-danger"/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="quotationId" wicket:id="quotationIdLabel"></label>
                    <div>
                        <input wicket:id="quotationId" type="text" size="20"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="product" wicket:id="productLabel"></label>
                    <div>
                        <select class="form-control" wicket:id="product"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="contract" wicket:id="contractLabel"></label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="hidden" wicket:id="contract"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding: 0">
                    <label for="customer" wicket:id="customerLabel"></label>
                    <div>
                        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" wicket:id="customer"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="serviceLevel" wicket:id="serviceLevelLabel"></label>
                    <div>
                        <select class="form-control" wicket:id="serviceLevel"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="equipmentType" wicket:id="equipmentTypeLabel"></label>
                    <div>
                        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" wicket:id="equipmentType"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="commodity" wicket:id="commodityLabel"></label>
                    <div>
                        <select class="form-control" wicket:id="commodity"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <span class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="originCountry" wicket:id="originCountryLabel"></label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="hidden" style="display: inline-block;" wicket:id="originCountry"/>
                    </div>
                </span>

                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="originDgfStation" wicket:id="originDgfStationLabel"></label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="hidden" wicket:id="originDgfStation"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="destinationCountry" wicket:id="destinationCountryLabel"></label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="hidden" wicket:id="destinationCountry"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="destinationDgfStation" wicket:id="destinationDgfStationLabel"></label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="hidden" wicket:id="destinationDgfStation"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="shippingTerms" wicket:id="shippingTermsLabel"></label>
                    <div>
                        <select class="form-control" wicket:id="shippingTerms"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

</wicket:panel>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add class "p-0" for 0 padding to the div you want,

`class="other-class p-0"`

Answer (score 1):

Try more specific selector like this:

```
.form-group .form-control {
    padding: 0;
}
```